# css let text first expand height then width

Tags: css

Is there a way so text stretches its container first in its height and if it reached its `max-height` that it proceeds in the horizontal direction and expands the width?

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 12px;
  max-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque alias optio, fugiat porro quo molestiae illo laborum ipsam consequuntur? Repudiandae facere pariatur veniam repellat, aliquid dolorum repellendus eum laborum natus.</div>
</div>
```

So every `.block` first takes the maximum height and after that expands if needed in its width.

I hope I was able to make the desired behavior understandable.

Comment: Why not replacing `max-height` with `height`?

Comment: I want the element as small as possible but if needer it shold expand in the given order.

Comment: Not with CSS... **NO**. That's not the way text flows.

Comment: I too know that this is not the default way but I hoped that there might be a css property which you could use.